# What is the amplitude of this function

Tags: trigonometry

What is the amplitude if I have these two functions?

$$y1: y=\cos(x)$$
$$y2: 2y=3\cos(3x/2)$$

I answered 3 but it was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the form on which the function is given to you: $2\cdot y = 3\cdot\cos\frac{3x}{2}$ (dots added by me for clarity). To get the amplitude of this function just by looking at the factor in front of the sinusouid ($\cos$ in this case) you first have to put the function definition on a form where $y$ stands alone:

$$y = \frac{3}{2}\cos\frac{3x}{2}$$

Now you recognize what the amplitude is, right?